# Tools to test OS performance

Tags: load-testing

I'm looking for suggestions/advice on what tools can help test for performance of Operating Systems (Windows and Mac). For example, monitor for performance stats (cpu, mem, disk usage) before and then after a certain agent (i.e. security software) is loaded on a system.
I am aware of PerfMon on windows. I am open to all and any suggestions and any help/advice is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for one tool that could be used on all these platforms? On Linux (and perhaps Mac), you can set up Telegraf along with an InfluxDB and build a dashboard on top of that (e.g. Grafana), that works just fine as a monitoring tool. But I'm unsure of whether or not this could be used on Windows as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) which can be used for collecting various [performance metrics](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent/blob/master/README.md#supported-metrics) across [variety of platforms](https://github.com/hyperic/sigar/blob/master/bindings/java/src/org/hyperic/sigar/OperatingSystem.java)

Moreover you will be able to use [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) load testing capabilities to conduct the required load onto the operating system under test.

Check out [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/) for more detailed information and instructions.

Comment: Thank you for this info.
I apologize for (perhaps) ignorant question but isn't Jmeter a tool used for web application performance? and/or Web server performance? or can it also be used to monitor and collect perfomance stats on endpoint devices (laptops) with Windows or Mac OS?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can collect performance stats (CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, etc. metrics using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/)

Comment: Got it, is there a difference between using JMeter PerfMon Plugin and the Perfmon Windows Native tool? does this also work on MacOS?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the popular tools can help you test OS performance and monitor various performance metrics such as CPU usage, memory usage, disk usage, etc:

1. PerfMon: PerfMon or Performance Monitor is a built-in tool in Windows that can help you monitor various system performance metrics. It can also help you generate reports to analyze system performance over a specific period.
2. Activity Monitor: Activity Monitor is a built-in tool in Mac OS that allows you to monitor system performance metrics. You can also use Activity Monitor to monitor specific processes and their resource usage.
3. Sysinternals Suite: The Sysinternals Suite is a collection of advanced system utilities for Windows that can help you monitor system performance metrics in real-time. It includes tools such as Process Explorer, Process Monitor, and more.
4. htop: htop is a command-line utility for Linux and Unix-based systems that can help you monitor system performance metrics such as CPU usage, memory usage, and more. It provides a user-friendly interface and allows real-time process monitoring.
5. top: top is another command-line utility for Linux and Unix-based systems that can help you monitor system performance metrics in real-time. It provides a list of processes and their resource usage and allows you to sort processes based on different metrics.
6. Nagios: Nagios is an open-source monitoring tool that can help you monitor various system performance metrics in real-time. It allows you to monitor system resources such as CPU, memory, disk usage, and more. It also allows you to set up alerts and notifications based on specific thresholds.

In addition to these tools, there are also several commercial tools available that can help you monitor system performance metrics. Some popular commercial tools include SolarWinds Server & Application Monitor, AppDynamics, and New Relic.

References:

- PerfMon: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/perfmon
- Activity Monitor: https://support.apple.com/guide/activity-monitor/welcome/mac
- Sysinternals Suite: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysinternals-suite
- htop: https://htop.dev/
- top: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html
- Nagios: https://www.nagios.org/